# Select statement with a Split function

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using a select split function in stored procedure to pass a multiple selection IDS like below .

```
SELECT     Status AS ClientInbox, COUNT(submitTime) AS CountStatus
        FROM         dbo.ClientInbox with (nolock) join debtor with (nolock) on ClientInbox.debtorid = debtor.id
        WHERE      (submitTime >= @fromDate and submittime <= @toDate)
         and debtor.clientid IN  (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[split_IDs] (@clientid,','))
        GROUP BY Status
```

Where [dbo].[split_IDs] is a function. My problem is while testing, when i replcae the variable @clientid with a set of setrings like ('1,2,3,4,5'), the query returns the required records. But when i run the procedure from VS, it does not return the exact records. I try to figure out what the problem is by executing the procedure in the SQL server as below

```
USE [Volare_2005]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int
DECLARE @fromDate datetime
DECLARE @toDate datetime

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GetSMSReportDate]
        @fromDate = '2000-04-06T12:23:45',
        @toDate =  '2013-10-22T21:10:12',
        @option = 0 ,
        @collectorid = 0,
        @supervisorid = 0,
        @clientid = N'95,1'

--SELECT    'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

It fails the return the records as well. However it works fine when i run the query by replcaing the variable @clientid in the procedure. I am not sure were i go wrong. Please any help would be appreciate

Comment: What is the datatype of your variable @clientid in your stored procedure?

Comment: Its a nvarchar and the column debtor.clientid is bigInt

Comment: any length specified for that variable?

Comment: Can you try `SELECT CAST(ID AS BIGINT) FROM [dbo].[split_IDs] (@clientid,',')`

Comment: You say you run the query from VS. Could you please post the value your VS project sends to the procedure? (Debug your program and check the variable @clientid your program sends to your proc. 
I have a feeling that's where your problem is